# Is there a way to show python generated plots in the python interpreter console?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

I use emacs for most python programming, but really miss the inline plot feature combined with printed output in Spyder. See picture.

[image]

I've been experimenting with various interpreter settings but none seem to work:

```
(use-package python
  :config
  ;; (setq python-shell-interpreter "ipython"
       ;; python-shell-interpreter-args "-i --simple-prompt")
  (setq python-shell-interpreter "jupyter"
        python-shell-interpreter-args "console --simple-prompt"))
```

Is there a way to setup this functionality in Emacs?

Answer (score 2):

You may wanna checkout [ein](https://github.com/millejoh/emacs-ipython-notebook). Also, spacemacs has a [ipython-notebook](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Blang/ipython-notebook) layer setup based on that; perhaps you can use that as a reference for your own config.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use emacs-jupyter.

Try installing with `M-x package-install jupyter` (it's in Melpa) or follow the instructions on the [Github](https://github.com/nnicandro/emacs-jupyter).

Then configure it to put output (such as plots) into the REPL buffer with `(setq jupyter-repl-echo-eval-p t)`. Without this, output from plots will go into a separate pop-up buffer.

Then call a Jupyter shell as `M-x jupyter-run-repl` (instead of the usual `M-x run-python`).

You should be able to verify that it is working quickly (inside the shell you opened). A tip, when you are plotting: you want to say (in your python code) `fig.set_facecolor('w')` to make things more readable.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
fig.set_facecolor('w')

plt.scatter([1,2,3], [4,5,3])
```

Comment: Wow thanks, this is amazing